# Comparing Value Ranges Between 2 Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have an oracle 10g database that has 2 tables:  a REBATES table, and an ORDERS table.

The REBATES table looks sort of like this:

```
| rebate_percentage | min_purchase |
------------------------------------
| 1.0               | 5000         |
| 1.5               | 7000         |
| 2.0               | 11000        |
| 5.0               | 20000        |
```

I'm trying to determine the rebate percentage to apply, based on total orders.  I know how to find the sum of all orders for a particular customer, for a particular time range, but how do I also grab the rebate percentage, all in one query?

For example, if the order total is 16,000 then how can I construct a query that takes this value, compares it against the REBATES table, and returns 2.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way is if you have a min and max purchase amounts:

```
select rebate_percentage, min_purchase,
       (lead(min_purchase, 1) over (order by min_purchase) - 1) as max_purchase
from rebates
```

Then you can do a simple between join, where the join condition looks like:

```
on totalorders between rebates.min_purchase and rebates.max_purchase
```

You can handle the final case (with NULLs) with a modified join condition:

```
on totalorders >= rebates.min_purchase and
    (totalorders <= rebates.max_purchase or rebates.max_purchase is null)
```

Or, alternatively, by changing the original logic to have a coalesce() on the lead function with some very large value.

Comment: You might have to add logic to handle NULL values for max_purchase (not 100% sure what lead() returns for the last row, I assume NULL)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: One more thing ,if me make a join to orders table ,then only those records are populating whose value are between the min and max purchase range .If the order value lower then lowest min purchase then its rebate should be 0 .

Comment: @Gordon:Please correct you solution :`or rebates.max_purchase is null` not `totalorders  is null`  +1 for your solution :)

Answer (score 3):

use Functions:

Example:

```
FUNCTION RebatePercentage(purchase Number) RETURN NUMBER IS 
   rebateVal NUMBER;
   minPurchase NUMBER;
BEGIN

   SELECT MAX(min_purchase)
   INTO minPurchase
   FROM REBATES
   WHERE min_purchase <= purchase;

   SELECT rebate_percentage
   INTO rebateVal
   FROM REBATES WHERE min_purchase = minPurchase;

   RETURN ( rebateVal );
END;
```

Now you can call this function in your query

```
SELECT RebatePercentage(purchase_amt) from orders;
```